# Vb aspx project, I need help to understand the logic behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm a java programmer and for the first time I need to face a VB and ASP.NET web project.
I found some very basic tutorials on how ASP.NET works but I didn't understand very well how the logic behind works.
This project consist of lot of coupled files, the main pattern I found is:

- file.ascx
- file.ascx.designer.vb
- file.ascx.vb
- file2.aspx
- file2.aspx.designer.vb
- file2.aspx.vb

How do these file work and interact? I'm trying to understand it in a MVC logic but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the MVC logic in your head. ASPX doesn't use the MVC (at least by default).

The code files you see are grouped in two:

- ascx: markup file. On the fly converted to VB.NET > MSIL;
- ascx.vb: the code behind file. This one is merged with the generated code from the markup file (thanks to the `partial` keyword in the class declaration).

The `ascx` file is a control file, the `aspx` file is a page file. A page file can consist of zero or more controls, defined by the ASP.NET team, third party developers or you. If you want a custom control, you can create an own control by creating an `ascx` and `ascx.vb` file (or let Visual Studio do it for you).

Comment: I don't seem to have .cs files, the file extension I found to be generated are the one I descripted. So aspx is a page (like a jsp, right?), ascx file handles the logic? Or it handles the input I put in the aspx page?

Comment: Sorry, `.vb` indeed. I am not familiar with JSP. Will elaborate a little more in my answer.

Comment: **If you want a custom control, you can create an own control by creating an ascx and ascx.vb file (or let Visual Studio do it for you).**

generated some doubts in me. Both are automatically generated by a piece a code in aspx i want to replicate, or once i make the aspx visual studio generated the vb file?

Comment: They are both created from a template when you create a 'new page', or a 'new control'.

Comment: That's generating even more doubts into me. So I could make web-apps without writing a line of code? Is it handled automatically? Sorry I seem to be not very into this way of thinking.

Comment: You can use the built-in designer, but eventually that will lead to HTML code in your aspx or ascx file at least.

Answer (score 0):

**aspx** files usually will have the UI and will which is usually HTML tags, some ASP.NET server control embed code. **aspx.vb** file (codebehind) will have server-side coding in VB.NET.

In the MVC logic, *you can* relate aspx page to View and aspx.vb to Controller action methods.